# Adding Foreign Objects as React Components in a D3 svg node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg

I am working on a D3 React requirement where in if user clicks on a rectangle on svgm an input box is provided for text. I want to use that input for updating another component in react app. How do I do that using foreign object in svg. Is there any other way I can link a text box with a rectangle(drawn just above each rectangle) in d3 in React.

My existing code snippet is here

```js
d3.select('svg#target')
  .append("g")
      .selectAll("whatever")
      .data([1,2,3,4])
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        var x = 200 * Math.sin(-60 * i * (Math.PI / 180));
        return x - 50;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        var y = 200 * Math.cos(-60 * i * (Math.PI / 180));
        return y - 20;
      })

      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("height", 40)
      .attr("fill", "gray")
      .on("click", function(d, i) {
        const count = i;
        d3.select(this)
          .append("foreignObject")
          .attr("x", function() {
            return 300 * Math.sin(-60 * i * (Math.PI / 180)) + 50;
          })
          .attr("y", function() {
            return 280 * Math.cos(-60 * i * (Math.PI / 180));
          })
          .attr("width", 140)
          .attr("height", 20)
          .html(function(d, i) {
            return (
              '<input type="text" id="attribute' +
              count +
              'value="Text goes here" />'
            );
          });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="-250 -250 500 500" width="400" id="target"></svg>
```

Comment: Try to always pose the question as a minimal reproducible example. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I edited your answer to try to do this.

Comment: @b-kalra did you maybe find an answer to this? I am struggling to render a custom context menu over a d3 rect which is passed through .each() function, so far no luck. Let me know if you have some additional info on this matter

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close, you only need to change it so that the foreign object is not appended inside the `<rect />`, but rather inserted as a sibling, like:

```html
<g>
  <rect x="-50" y="180" width="100" height="40" fill="gray"> 
  </rect>
  <rect x="-223.20508075688772" y="80.00000000000003" width="100" height="40" fill="gray">
  </rect>
  <rect x="-223.20508075688775" y="-119.99999999999996" width="100" height="40" fill="gray">
  </rect>
  <rect x="-50.0" y="-220" width="100" height="40" fill="gray">
  </rect>

  <foreignObject x="-50.0" y="-220" width="100" height="40">
    <input type="text" id="attribute3" value="text goes here">
  </foreignObject>
</g>
```

We can do this with this on line 24: `d3.select(this.parentNode)` which selects the parent, so now when we append, it becomes a sibling of the `<rect />`, rather than a child.

```js
d3.select('svg#target')
  .append("g")
      .selectAll("whatever")
      .data([1,2,3,4])
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        var x = 200 * Math.sin(-60 * i * (Math.PI / 180));
        return x - 50;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        var y = 200 * Math.cos(-60 * i * (Math.PI / 180));
        return y - 20;
      })

      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("height", 40)
      .attr("fill", "gray")
      .on("click", function(d, i) {
        const count = i;
        if (document.getElementById('attribute' + count)){
          return 0;
        }
        d3.select(this.parentNode)
          .append("foreignObject")
          .attr("x", function() {
             var x = 200 * Math.sin(-60 * i * (Math.PI / 180));
        return x - 50;
          })
          .attr("y", function() {
            var y = 200 * Math.cos(-60 * i * (Math.PI / 180));
        return y - 20;
          })
          .attr("width", 100)
          .attr("height", 40)
          .html(function(d, i) {
            return (
              `<input type="text" id="attribute${count}"
              style="height: 40px;" value="Text goes here" />`
            );
          });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewbox="-250 -250 500 500" width="400"  id="target"></svg>
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: This does not solve my actual problem. I liked your answer but my question was more related to react component. How do I add a react component as a foreign object? Now if user changes value in that input box, how do I notify parent component in the React App.

Comment: Ok, please add your react code (As a minimal reproducible example) and your attempt to solve it in your question and then I can try to update my answer.